# Custom SIFT detector in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, sift

Is there a way to specify custom SIFT detector parameters in OpenCV?

It seems that the [FeatureDetector constructor](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html#featuredetector) does not take any parameter, whereas it seems possible to specify those parameters in the [SIFT constructor](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/nonfree/doc/feature_detection.html#SIFT%20%3a%20public%20Feature2D).

I am working on logo detection. 
Some of the logos have very low texture information, so I would like to detect more keypoints when there are too few (I could increase the edgeThreshold of SIFT?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to create a [custom SIFT descriptor extractor](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/nonfree/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=sift#SIFT%20%3a%20public%20Feature2D):

```
SIFT siftDetectorExtractor = SIFT(200, 3, 0.04, 15, 1.6);

Mat logo = imread("logoName.jpg");

vector<KeyPoint> keyPoints;
Mat sifts;
siftDetectorExtractor(logo, Mat(), keyPoints, sifts);
```

or use the detector-class:

```
Ptr<FeatureDetector> detector = Ptr<FeatureDetector>( new SIFT( <your arguments> ) );
```